# Record 'missing' if field is empty

Tags: crystal-reports

My report's data source is an MDB file created from Raiser’s Edge. The report displays constituent info (name, address, home phone, cell phone, etc.) alongside with some transaction info (where constituents in the non-profit are like customers in the corporate world.)

When I include name and address, every record in the data source is displayed even if the address is missing from the data source. However, when I add either type of phone number, *only* records that have that type of phone number are displayed. In other words, the constituents are displayed, even if they don’t have an address (obviously, the address field will be blank in the report).

However, if they don’t have the type of phone I prefer, the whole record disappears. If I remove the phone number, the missing records appear again.

In this specific case, there are 28 records in the source, 18 of which have a home phone number. If I include only name and address, all 28 are in the report even without an address. When I add the home phone number to the report, only those 18 with a number display.

Instead of including the phone as a database field, I tried including it as a formula to convert the Null/Empty strings:

```
IF IsNull({CnPh_1.CnPh_1_Phone_number}) OR {CnPh_1.CnPh_1_Phone_number} = ""
THEN "-"
ELSE {CnPh_1.CnPh_1_Phone_number}
```

I still have the same problem: Records without a phone number won't display. (This type of code works for the address: Records without addresses display the "-" sign.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you include a photo of the issue and the expected output

Comment: Sounds to me like your tables are incorrectly joined. If data can't be found, an improper Join relationship will make otherwise-valid data disappear. How comfortable are you with the concept of SQL Joins?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the join type from "Inner Join" to "Left Outer Join" and it is working now.